# D struct memory handling - return `this` from member function

Tags: d

```
uint ci = 0;

struct S
{
    uint i;

    this(int x)
    {
        i = ci;
        ci++;

        writeln("new: ", i);
    }

    this(this)
    {
        i = ci;
        ci++;

        writeln("copy ", i);
    }

    ~this()
    {
        writeln("del ", i);
    }

    S save1() // produces 2 copies in total
    {
        S s = this;
        return s;
    }

    auto save2() // produces 3 copies in total
    {
        S s = this;
        return s;
    }
}
```

Save1:

```
S s = S(1);
S t = S(1);

t = s.save1();

// Gives:
// new 0
// new 1
// copy 2
// del 1
// del 2
// del 0
```

Save2:

```
S s = S(1);
S t = S(1);

t = s.save2();

// Gives:
// new 0
// new 1
// copy 2
// copy 3
// del 3
// del 1
// del 3
// del 0
```

As you can see, the save2() variant never 'deletes' the struct with i == 2. Is it memory leaking? I cannot properly manage my resources in structs if I use `auto` as return type.

Also, if save() simply return `this` without the temporary, I get:

```
S save()
{
    return this;
}

// new 0
// new 1
// copy 2
// del 1
// del 2
// del 2
```

Are these bugs? How am I supposed to do proper memory management if I cannot define a default constructor? What is the reason behind this design decision?

I want to use it for a forward range, so I cannot use `class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me.  Apparently the only difference between `save1` and `save2` is that the latter uses `auto` return instead of an explicit return type.  Except in a few corner cases that don't apply here, this should have no effect on postblit and d'tor calls.

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce the wrong-code part with git dmd:

```
new: 0
new: 1
copy 2
del 1
del 2
del 0
-
new: 0
new: 1
copy 2
copy 3
del 2
del 1
del 3
del 0
-
new: 0
new: 1
copy 2
del 1
del 2
del 0
```

I filed the remaining NRVO issue as http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=7353

Comment: I used the latest release, so maybe it's already (partly) fixed then.